# Positive solution of the PDE: $u_t=\Delta u+au-buv$, am I missing something?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, lp-spaces, weak-derivatives

Consider the following system of partial differential equations taken from [this paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022039607000137):[image]

[image]

I just want to know how the author got the inequality:

[image]

I feel something is wrong since the term $a-bv$ may be nonpositive. Am I missing something?

Comment: $u u^-$ is either zero or $(u^-)^2$. So the problem basically reduces to showing that $a-bv$ restricted to $\{ u<0 \}$ is $L^2$. I'm not sure how they expect to do that part, though.

Comment: @Ian given the regularity assumptions on $\Omega$, I think they are assuming $u$ and $v$ are classical solutions, in which case $v$ is certainly bounded

Comment: @Jason But one of the goals of the lemma itself is to show that $v$ is bounded.

Comment: If $v$ is a classical solution (please correct me if we are not assuming this), then $v$ is at the very least continuous on a compact set and therefore is bounded. The main point of the exercise is to show that $u$ and $v$ are both positive, and get an explicit upper bound for $v$.

Comment: @Jason Yes the solutions are classical. However, here the time $T$ as I understand refers to the maximal time of existence (because the global existence will follow after), so either $T=\infty$ or else $T<\infty$ and the solution explodes at $T$.